# How can i get query result id in controller from Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to take houses lists and houses pictures on mysql from laravel. But, i have this problem. Using the process below:

```
$houses = Houses::query()
             ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
             ->take('6')
             ->get();
```

This query, give houses list to me. And I need to use the houses I retrieve to get their photos, this is the best I could think of:

```
$pictures = Housephotos::query()
            ->where('house_id', '=', $houses->house_id)
            ->get();
```

Question one: This process is correct? 
Question two : How can do this?

Comment: What is your problem so ?

Comment: `$houses` is a `Collection` of `House` objects, so `$houses->house_id` is invalid. You should define a relationship between `Houses` and `Housephotos`, then use `Houses::with(["Housephotos"])->where(...)->get();` to get each `House` and it's `Housephoto` (single or multiple depending on the relationship). Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships for more info.

Comment: _"How can i write my project?"_ Wouldn't it be fun if there was a website where you could ask that and receive the complete source code, free of charge!

Comment: @EmileBergeron That's not what I want to say! I want to say this: what is true way!!

Comment: Yeah I understood the meaning, don't worry. I think [Tim Lewis comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308267/how-can-i-get-query-result-id-in-controller-from-laravel?noredirect=1#comment77578702_45308267) is on point.

Comment: Thank u @TimLewis. Maybe i couldn't understand. So that, i'm asking again. `Houses::with(["Housephotos"])->where(...)->get();` I must get dynamic id. Like this:
`<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while ($list = mysql_fetch_object($query)) { 
     $get_lessons = mysql_query("SELECT  name FROM lessons WHERE user_id = '$list->user_id'");
   $lesson = mysql_fetch_object($get_lessons);
   echo $lessons->name.'<br>';
}
?>`

Comment: Do some research into how to use relationships via Laravel Eloquent; you shouldn't have to do queries in loops if you do, as `->with(...)` will query and join results, meaning you can access a `Houses` relationship with something as simple as `$house->housephoto->name;`. Forget `myslq_*` function if you're using Laravel; use what's available to you, and that's `Eloquent`

Comment: @TimLewis thank u so much. I'm beginner for Laravel. I will research.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a relationship between `Housephotos` and `House` so that there is house_id in Housephotos. If this is true, you can already use the houses Id you have to retrieve the houses Id:

Say you already have the houses, then you can have:

```
$pictures = Housephotos::whereIn('house_id', '=', $houses->pluck('id')->toArray())
        ->get();
```

This will give you the houses photos.

Answer (score 0):

Add a relation to Houses:

```
class Houses extends Model 
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Housephotos::class);
    }
}
```

and now you can get the photos easily like:

```
$houses = Houses::query()
             ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
             ->take('6')
             ->get();

foreach ($houses->photos as $photo) {
    echo $photo->id;
}
```

the problem with that is, select query will run n times (5 times for this example).

if you add `with` to the query however, then laravel will run a single `in` query to get the pictures:

```
$houses = Houses::query()
             ->with('pictures')
             ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
             ->take('6')
             ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @madpoet. But i have a problem. Firstly; when i make this: 
`$houses = Houses::query()
             ->with('pictures')
             ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
             ->take('6')
             ->get();`
such an error occuring: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'houses_pictures.houses_id' in...` However, in the houses_pictures table, there is no such column. But, `house_id` is present...

And second, if i make like as above, how can i data pass to view, with `foreach`

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). You can define the foreign key name like `$this->hasMany(Housephotos::class, 'houses_id')`. You'll have less trouble if you follow the conventions: `Houses` should be `House`. You can pass $houses to view and loop with @foreach inside the template.